# Xamarin Forms facebook Login Xamarin.Auth

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.auth

I'm new to Xamarin forms and I'd like to build an application with a Facebook login button and Xamarin.Auth. I found a lot of stuff online but I can't find a way to make it work. Maybe because I found some old implementations or because of my project configuration i'm not really sure what's wrong with it.

I'm working on a MacBookPro so I use Xamarin Studio for Mac and I want to build this application for Android and iOS first but it might be extended later to Windows phone.

**Here are the versions I use:**

- Xamarin Studio Community Version: 6.1.1 (build 15)
- NuGet Version: 3.4.3.0
- Xamarin.Android Version: 7.0.1.2 (Xamarin Studio Community)
- Apple Developer Tools: Xcode 8.0 (11246) Build 8A218a
- Xamarin.Mac Version: 2.10.0.103 (Xamarin Studio Community)
- Xamarin.iOS Version: 10.0.1.8 (Xamarin Studio Community)
- Operating System: Mac OS X 10.11.6

I tried the following example but I couldn't find a way to make it working:

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/xamarin.auth

As I am a novice with Xamarin.Forms and more globally with Mobile Application development I have no clue where to put the Code they provide.

So I tried to put the OAuth2Authenticator in my LoginPage together with the auth.Completed event so when the user is authenticated I can save the Account data a show my MainPage

I tried to run the app like that, it doesn't trigger any errors.
I then tried to display the facebook button on the page with

```
auth.GetUI ()
```

But it gives me the following error message:

> 'OAuth2Authenticator' does not contain a definition for 'GetUI' and no extension method 'GetUI' accepting a first argument of type 'OAuth2Authenticator' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I feel like it's almost working but I can't get the Facebook button. How can I display it?

Comment: `GetUI` is in the platform-specific code, not in Xamarin.iOS. You can do this via a dependacy service or look at the start of the Forms version: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/tree/portable-bait-and-switch/source/XamarinForms

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
Do you know a tutorial to create a dependancy service? I'm kind of lost in this mobile application architecture...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/852742/Simple-Twitter-client-using-Xamarin-Forms-Xamarin

just change following code :

```
                var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator(
                               clientId: "your facebook clientId",
                               scope: "email",
                               authorizeUrl: new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/"),
                               redirectUrl: new Uri("https://www.google.com/")
                           );
```

Comment: I have an error message in my iOS project folder LoginPageRenderer.cs:
the type or namespace name 'Auth' does not exist in the namspace 'Xamarin'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
I thought it would refer to my shared project Xamarin.Auth but it doesn't so I tried to add Xamarin.Auth to my Project.iOS packages:
Could not install package 'Validation 2.0.4.14103'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework.

Comment: are you add Xamarin.Auth in IOS Project?

Comment: OK actually I found a solution. I couldn't add Xamarin.Auth as a package, it trigger some errors so I've add it as a component and it works.
Thanks all :)